# IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds stratify sklearn test_train_split

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am using a pandas dataframe in the sklearn cross_validation train_test_split module.

```
d=pandas.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(300),
                    'c':np.array([el for el in np.ones(100)]+
                                 [el for el in np.zeros(200)])})
from sklearn import cross_validation
(X,y)=(d['a'],d['c'])
```

This works

```
X_train_and_cv, X_test,y_train_and_cv,y_test = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
X_train, X_cv,y_train,y_cv = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(X_train_and_cv,y_train_and_cv,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
X_train_and_cv, X_test,y_train_and_cv,y_test = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0,stratify=y)
X_train, X_cv,y_train,y_cv = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(X_train_and_cv,y_train_and_cv,test_size=0.2,random_state=0,stratify=y)

in _is_valid_list_like(self, key, axis)
   1536         l = len(ax)
   1537         if len(arr) and (arr.max() >= l or arr.min() < -l):
-> 1538             raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds")
   1539 
   1540         return True

IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Your second call to `train_test_split` uses a different array length for `stratify` than the `y` you use. Use `stratify=y_train_and_cv`.

---

First, a little side note: `cross_validation` (0.17.1 docs [here](http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html#sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split)) will be deprecated soon, you should use [`model_selection.train_test_split (0.18.1)`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) instead. I'll import `train_test_split itself` to shorten the length of what follows:

```
# Same as this in older versions:
# from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

This is fine:

```
X_train_and_cv, X_test,y_train_and_cv,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,
                                                                test_size=0.2,
                                                                random_state=0,
                                                                stratify=y)
```

This is not fine since `y=y_train_and_cv`(len=240) `stratify=y` (len=300)

```
X_train, X_cv,y_train,y_cv = train_test_split(X_train_and_cv,
                                              y_train_and_cv,
                                              test_size=0.2,
                                              random_state=0,
                                              stratify=y)
```

replace it by:

```
X_train, X_cv,y_train,y_cv = train_test_split(X_train_and_cv,
                                              y_train_and_cv,
                                              test_size=0.2,
                                              random_state=0,
                                              stratify=y_train_and_cv)
```

Comment: Wow, I now realize that I was interpreting `y` as a string instead of variable argument--e.g., stratify = 'yes' --and assuming that it was inferring the to-stratify-on array by the second argument..

Comment: Ah! That would have been stratify=True :)